# Disjoint algebraically independent sets

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field, transcendental-numbers

Let $A,B\subset\Bbb R$ algebraically independent sets over $\Bbb Q$ and $A\cap B=\emptyset.$ Let $T$ be a transcdental basis of $\Bbb R$ over $\Bbb Q$ such that $A,B\subset T.$
Now, $qA$ is algebraically independent over $\Bbb Q$ for any  $q\in\Bbb Q\setminus\{0\}$, easy to see.

Moreover, $qA\cap B=\emptyset.$ assume not, that is, $qA\cap B\neq\emptyset.$ So, there exists $qa=b$, where $a\in A$ and $b\in B$. So, $f(x,y)=qx-y$ is a nonzero polyoinmal such that $f(a,b)=0$ which a contradiction since $\{a,b\}\subset A\cup B.$
Is that right?

Comment: @egreg, is that right?

Comment: Do you *assume* that there is a transcendence basis $T$ of $\mathbb{R}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ with $A, B \subseteq T$, or do you claim that this always exists? The latter would be false: one could have $A = \{ \pi \}$ and $B = \{ 2\pi \}$. This also yields a counterexample to your claim that $qA \cap B = \emptyset$ for all $q \in \mathbb{Q} \setminus \{ 0 \}$.

Comment: @ I assumed there exists a transcdental basis $T$ such that $A, B\subset T$

Comment: @Bib-lost Is it clear now?